# How to get the current location,mouse position and current url using javascript browser detect

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a tool to monitor a website.

For that I need to get the current location, mouse position, and current url using javascript browser detection

How can I do this?

I know that the code below is correct for getting the current position.

```
var loc = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition;
console.log(loc);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To access a property of an object use a `.` (period) not a `,` (comma)
2. `getCurrentPosition` is a *function*, you need to call it (with `()`)
3. `getCurrentPosition` may have to make network requests in order to figure out the result, so it is asynchronous. You have to pass it a callback function as its first argument.

Such:

```
function showPositionData(result) {
    console.log(result);
}
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPositionData);
```